# How to copy a file from one dir to another in Firebase Storage with the Admin SDK

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I want to copy a file in Firebase Storage from one location */dir/a/myfile.jpg* to */dir/b/myfile.b* using the AdminSDK with Kotlin/Java.

My code for uploading the file is below. How can I copy the file to another directory without uploading it twice?

```kotlin
        val imageName = generateFileName(file.originalFilename)
        val map: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
        map["firebaseStorageDownloadTokens"] = "$publicDir/$imageName"
        val blobId = BlobId.of(FirebaseApp.getInstance().options.storageBucket, "$publicDir/$imageName")
        val blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId)
            .setMetadata(map)
            .setContentType(file.contentType)
            .build()
        val storage = fireBaseConfig.firebaseStorage()
        val blob = storage.create(blobInfo, file.inputStream.readAllBytes())
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way how to do this but I am not sure if it is optimal. I used the function `copyTo` on Blob and provided a BlobId with a different directory and it worked.

I would be interested if there is better way of doing this because I think `storage.get(blobId)` is a costly operation.

```kotlin
val blobId = BlobId.of(FirebaseApp.getInstance().options.storageBucket, "$privateDir/$blobIdUrl")
val newBlobId = BlobId.of(FirebaseApp.getInstance().options.storageBucket, "$publicDir/$newImageName")
val storage = fireBaseConfig.firebaseStorage()
val blob = storage.get(blobId)
val map: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
map["publishedByUserId"] = userId
val newBlobInfo = BlobInfo
      .newBuilder(newBlobId)
      .setMetadata(map)
      .setContentType(blob.contentType)
      .setCacheControl("public,max-age=1209600")
      .build()

val newBlob = blob.copyTo(newBlobId)
blob.storage.update(newBlobInfo)
```